# Decode json dart flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, decode

I need to decode the following JSON in Dart. When I perform the decoding, I encounter the following error. How can I resolve this?

**Error:** type '(Map<dynamic, dynamic>) => RicettaNew' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic' of 'f'

**JSON:**

```
[{"name":"ricetta1","values":
[{"key":"item1","value":"3"},
{"key":"item2","value":"8"},{"key":"item3","value":"13"}
,{"key":"item4","value":"18"},{"key":"item5","value":"23"},{"key":"item6","value":"14"},....
```

**Flutter Code:**

```
    var serverlink = "http://207.154.221.255:8600/api/recipes"+"/"+mc.model;
      var request = http.Request('GET', Uri.parse(serverlink));
      http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var result = await response.stream.bytesToString();
        print("result: "+result);
        var list = jsonDecode(result.toString());
        lista=jsonDecode(result).map((Map m)=> RicettaNew.fromJson(m)).toList();

...
class RicettaNew {
  String name;
  List<Values> values = [];

  RicettaNew(this.name, this.values);

  RicettaNew.fromJson(Map json) {
    name = json["name"];

  }
}
```

Comment: what is your lista?

Comment: @Nguyenfamily lista is var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change your base [] braces to {}

Because the json you want to pass is not correct json format

Json format always starts and ends with { … }

```
{   
    "name":"ricetta1",
    "values": [
            {"key":"item1","value":"3"},
            {"key":"item2","value":"8"},
            {"key":"item3","value":"13"},
                         {"key":"item4","value":"18"},
                         {"key":"item5","value":"23"}

            ]
}
```

before decoding parse your json on https://jsoneditoronline.org/ so you can identify its in right format or wrong

& generate your model class on https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/